# Calculate AVERAGEX

Tags: dax

I would like to calculate the average of a measure (ETP). I use this formula.

```
 Moyenne :=
SUMX (
    Personne;
    AVERAGEX (
        Lien_Contrat_SA_BP;
        CALCULATE (
            'Lien_Contrat_SA_BP'[ETP_Contractuel1];
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Temps'; Temps[Date] )
        )
    )
)
```

For the same month, I have two values.

For example :

```
January  1  
February 1  
March    1  
March    0.8
```

I would like to do this calculation
`(1 + 1 + 0.9) / 3` and not `(1 + 1 + 1 + 0.8)/4`

How can I do this? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the first column in your example called [Month] and the second column called [Value], this measure should give the avg you are looking for:

```
Measure =
AVERAGEX (
    SUMMARIZE ( Table1, Table1[Month], "avg", AVERAGE ( Table1[Value] ) ),
    [avg]
)
```

It works like this:

The SUMMARIZE-function creates a virtual summarized table, calculating the average for each month. Like this:

```
Month     avg    
January    1   
Febuary    1  
March     0.9
```

The AVERAGEX function then returns the average of the values in the resulting [avg] column.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this measure : 
SUMX (
    Personne;
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGEX (
            Temps;
            CALCULATE ( [ETP_Contractuel1]; ALL ( 'Temps' ); VALUES ( ‘Temps'[Mois] ) ) ) ) )

this is average for each month, but I do not get the overall average every month because it counts twice the month of August.